# Using an Object for A form Dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out how to turn this object and use it for the options for my dropdown but I'm having a hard time understanding how to even with the documentation on the CodeIgniter webiste.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [event_name] => First City Shodown
        [status_id] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [event_name] => First City Festival
        [status_id] => 1
    )

)

<?php 
$options = array(

);
?>
<?php echo form_dropdown('eventname', $options); ?>
```

Comment: What would you like to achieve as the final result?

Comment: A working dropdown with the id of the event as the value of the option and the event name as the text of the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is loop through each event object, and retrieve both the event id as well as the event name. This can be done quite easily with the use of a foreach loop, since the event objects are stored in an array.

Assuming those objects are stored in an array called `$events`:

```
$options = array();

foreach ( $events as $event ) {
    $options[$event->id] = $event->event_name;
}

echo form_dropdown('eventname', $options);
```

Comment: Well when there's no options normally the default with CI is I believe Please Select An Option how can I make it so that it does that it still adds that and makes it to where that can't be chosen as an option.

Comment: Are you sure CI adds that option by default? I don't remember it doing so, plus the documentation says it doesn't.

Comment: Well when I had an empty array that's what would always show up.

Comment: That's because there wouldn't be anything to show otherwise. However, there's generally no reason at all to show that 'Please select an option'. It should be clear what your dropdown menu does anyway, so I wouldn't worry too much about that.

Comment: But I'd rather it not show one of the actual options as the default selected option.

Comment: I guess I can understand that. You could just add an initial option to the `$options` array with a key of 'initial' or whatever you want to call it, and give it a value like 'Please select an option'. Then, when you process your form, you can check if the 'initial' option was selected, and deal with that accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$options = array();
foreach($array as $object){
    $options["{$object->id}"] = $object->event_name;
}
echo form_dropdown('eventname', $options);
```